# Php display image even if it was deleted

Tags: php, html

I am new on php and I have some very weird situation here. Basically, I wanted to display an image called `Default.jpg`. After that, I felt like this image is not suitable and decided to change it inside my picture folder. But, when I run my code again, it display back the first image instead of the one that I have changed. I deleted the image to try and test but, surprisingly, the image is still able to display as the first image.
Here is my code. I also check whether if the file exist and it display as file deleted.

```
<?php
    require_once('UserClass.php');
    session_start();
    //require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
    require_once('dbconfig/db_connection.php');

    //phpinfo();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Homepage</h2>
    <img src = "Default.jpg" id = "Avatar" />

    <?php
        $file = "Default.jpg";
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            echo ("file exist");
        } else {
            echo ("file deleted");
        }   
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The PHP check is runs on your server, and shows (correctly) that you've deleted the file The image tag is interpreted by your browser, and the browser has likely cached the 'Default.jpg' file. It has kept a copy locally, even though it no longer exists on the server. Try force-refreshing the page. (Ctrl+R, Apple+R or Ctrl+F5 depending on your browser)

Comment: `shift-ctrl-r` for a hard refresh

Answer (score 1):

You did not change the file name of the image, so browser uses the image cached.

You can clear the cache.

You also can add a parameter like to the image path like `<img src = "Default.jpg?v=2" id = "Avatar" />`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the image is saved on the cache of your browsers. Please try to clear cache of your browsers

> For Google Chrome:
>
> [Google Chrome Clear Cache Link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
>
> For Firefox:
>
> [Firefox Clear Cache Link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your browser cache and press ctrl + f5 to refresh.

Comment: Try to be more descriptive and complete with your answer so that it has more information about exactly what to do and why (ie. why `ctrl+F5` may work).

Answer (score 0):

As @Kris suggested make image name unique, so rather than hardcode number or value use a timestamp like this:

```
<img src="Default.jpg?someKey=<?php echo time(); ?>" id="Avatar" />
```

So it will always try to load new image from server, as timestamp is always unique,

Also if want to check this type of cases, clear the browser cache is a good idea, or you can also use `Private Window` in Firefox or `Incognito Window` in Chrome browser,